# install Riak KV on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, riak

i want to install Riak on ubuntu 14.04 using

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/basho/riak/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install riak=2.1.4-1
```

But get the error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package riak
```

my ubuntu version is

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Do i need ubuntu 64-bit, to install Riak? i have installed 32-bit. How could i install Riak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bikas, all of the packages for Riak KV are 64 bit and are not backwards compatible with 32 bit operating systems. You will need to install a 64 bit version of Ubuntu to run Riak KV: http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/setup/installing/debian-ubuntu/